# Why is "everybody" singular?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, word-usage, compounds

Why is "Everybody" in the singular?   We say "People in Europe are nice".    Why,  then, do we say "Everybody in Europe is nice"?

Comment: Every–body is a way of saying  "each individual person" . Would you say each individual person "are" or "is" nice?

Comment: _Each_ and _every_ are singular. _All_ is plural. _Any_ and _some_ can be either. It's like gender in French or German -- arbitrary features., no logical reason.

Comment: @JohnLawler gender is hardly arbitrary, but that is a way different discussion :D

Comment: @Helmar: Quite right. They look arbitrary from the outside, though, and that's all that matters from that vantage point. Native speakers can tell, but nobody else can.

Comment: The compound determinative "everybody" functions as determiner-head. The determinative base "every" has a distributive interpretation which is reflected in the singular head "body", and hence "everybody" takes singular verb agreement.

Comment: I was going to add something but BillJ took the words out of my mouth... yes, someone who is asking why "everybody" takes a singular verb, will now understand why.

Answer (score 5):

First, consider the sentence:

> Every dog is nice.

This sentence is composed of a quantifier ('every'), a noun ('dog'), a copula verb ('is'), and an adjective ('nice').

Notice that because 'dog' is singular, the singular form of *to be* is used, 'is'.

Now consider

> Everybody is nice.

You can think of 'everybody' as being composed of a quantifier ('every') and a noun ('body'). It is a kind of compound quantifier phrase. Notice that the "embedded" word 'body' is singular. This should go some way toward explaining why one must use the singular of *to be*, 'is'.

The same pattern occurs with other compound quantifier phrases like 'everyone' and 'everything'. For example,

> Everyone is nice.
>
> Everything is fine.